# Can't reference previously used elements in an iterator (java)

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, hashmap, iterator

When I use an iterator to go over elements of an entry set, I can't reference elements that have been previously been iterated over. Here's the more specific problem:

```
public void adjSetter(HashMap<ArrayList<Integer>,miniSquare> mp) {
    Iterator it = mp.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println("Hi~!");

        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        ArrayList<Integer> lis=(ArrayList<Integer>)pair.getKey();
        System.out.println(lis.get(0) + "  " + lis.get(1) + "Yerr");
        miniSquare minSqua=(miniSquare)pair.getValue();
        if((minSqua.yCord!=600)){
            lis.set(1,minSqua.yCord+50);
            minSqua.topSquare=mp.get(lis);
             System.out.println("This Square is " + minSqua.xCord + "  " +minSqua.yCord + " and its top square is " + lis.get(0) + " " + lis.get(1) + " And it's actually " + minSqua.topSquare.xCord + " " + minSqua.topSquare.yCord  ); }
        if(minSqua.yCord!=250){
            lis.set(1,minSqua.yCord-50);
            minSqua.bottomSquare=mp.get(lis);
            System.out.println("This Square is " + minSqua.xCord + "  " + minSqua.yCord + " and its bottom square is " + lis.get(0) + " " + lis.get(1) + " And it's actually " + minSqua.bottomSquare.xCord + " " + minSqua.bottomSquare.yCord );
            }
        if(minSqua.xCord!=550){
            lis.set(1,minSqua.yCord);
            lis.set(0,minSqua.xCord+50);
            minSqua.rightSquare=mp.get(lis);
            System.out.println("This Square is " + minSqua.xCord + "  " + minSqua.yCord + " and its right square is " + lis.get(0) + " " + lis.get(1) + " And it's actually " + minSqua.rightSquare.xCord + " " + minSqua.rightSquare.yCord );
        lis.set(0,450); lis.set(1,450); //The error line
            System.out.println(mp.get(lis).xCord+ "Yerd");}
        if(minSqua.xCord!=200){
            lis.set(1,minSqua.yCord);
            lis.set(0,minSqua.xCord-50);
            minSqua.leftSquare=mp.get(lis);
            System.out.println("This Square is " + minSqua.xCord + "  " + minSqua.yCord + " and its left square is " + lis.get(0) + " " + lis.get(1) + " And it's actually " + minSqua.leftSquare.xCord + " " + minSqua.leftSquare.yCord );// This line throws a null pointer exception if the other problem line is deleted 
        }

    }

}
```

After going through the element with key (450,450), the line

```
lis.set(0,450); lis.set(1,450);
```

yields a null pointer exception. Can anyone help understand how to fix this, or even what the problem really is? I'm sorry if there's insufficent information as is or if the code is hard to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure of the exact reason you got `NullPointerException`, but you are misusing `HashMap`. Even if you weren't in the middle of iterating over the entries of the `HashMap`, mutating a key of the `Map` (an `ArrayList<Integer>` in your case) breaks the `HashMap`, since it changes the `hashCode()` of a key already in the `Map` (which means the key may be stored in a bucket that doesn't match its new `hashCode()`).

This probably broke the iterator code and caused the `NullPointerException`. You should not mutate the keys of a `HashMap`. If you weren't iterating over the entries, you could have removed the entry from the `Map`, mutated the key, and put it back in the `Map`, but that's not allowed while iterating over the `Map`.

P.S., instead of using raw `Iterator` and `Map.Entry`, which requires casting later, use:

```
Iterator<Map.Entry<ArrayList<Integer>,miniSquare>> it = mp.entrySet().iterator();
```

and

```
Map.Entry<ArrayList<Integer>,miniSquare> pair = it.next();
```

This won't solve your exception, but it's good practice.